# CSS trouble: Float drops to another line (all browsers)

Tags: css, css-float

I understand that a float drops to the next line if its parent container is not wide enough.

The site I'm [working on](http://acrobotic.com) is a Magento 1.7.2 install with a ThemeForest theme (Fortis). The expected problem started when I included Twitter bootstrap (I obviously did it at the top of the ).

My `div.header` is 960px wide. It contains:

- `div.header-top` which is working fine.
- `h1.logo` which floats left, and is narrower than it needs to be (currently 200px, should be 400px).
- `div.header-left` element which is currently empty, and has a left margin of 20px.
- `div.header-right` element which is 485px wide and floats right.

The problem is that if I make `h1.logo` any wider, the `div.header-right` will drop to the next line.

I should be able to make the `div.header-left` as wide as 455px without a problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Are there margins on any of the elements?

Comment: Hey dsundy, thanks for the reply! Yep, checked the margins, and only the `div.header-left` has them on.  I'm missing 960px-200px-485px-20px=155px of space that I can't seem to find.

Comment: I set the logo to 400px and no problem. Or am I missing the question here?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: @KatieK, I agree that it was specific, but I provided enough information so that an answer could be provided... and it was.  I do not mind the extra work, but in this case it wasn't necessary for troubleshooting my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Looks like the search bar on the top has a margin on the bottom and is pushing `.header-right` over to the left.

Right click and "Inspect Element" on the search field and you will see what I mean.

You will have to remove the margin or adjust the height on `.header-top-search-wrapper`.

Comment: Aaaaaagh!!!!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I owe you a beer, my friend. 48hours later, I'm one happy man, f'in eh.

Comment: Haha. Glad to be of help! (I certainly know what that feels like).

Comment: well you can remove the margin on the form inside .header-top-search-wrapper